# Disappearing margin, when using Viewport Units AKA "VW", "VH"

Tags: html, css

[image: Example]

Here is the code sample, that is used in this example:

```css
.child {
  float: left;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 5vw;
  margin-left: .1vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;"></div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. - https://jsfiddle.net/678f5dfu/1/

Comment: nothing is disappering, it's all about calculation ... check your dev tools and you will see the margin and it's too small (under 0.5px) when size of window is small

Comment: When i set the margin between multiple <div> elements contained in a parent <div> element, if i set the margin using Absolute Lengths units such as px-pixels, the margin between the elements looks the same it is absolute and there is no problem. But if i set the margin using Relative Lengths in this case using vw-viewport width, the margin between some of the elements disappears!! https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXJx3.png

Comment: must be some strange rounding by the browser/s: If 0.1vw becomes less than 0.5px, I would expect it to disppear on smaller screens as it does between the first two elements in your image. But the strange thing is that it does *not* disappear between elements two and three, which leads me to think that the element position is calculated/rounded  before the margin is rounded

Comment: As @TemaniAfif says, if the margin drops to under .5px the browser can't render it...but that difference may be passed through the DOM elements which is why subsequent margins are sometimes not affected. When in doubt use px for margins.

Comment: If you always want at least some margin to remain, use calc() to set a minimum, e.g. `margin-left: calc(1px + .1vw)` will ensure your margins never go below 1px.

Comment: Is there a way i can ensure that all <div> elements are all positioned with same margin, using the vw-viewport width unit? I have tried before the calc() function, but the problem remains some elements get 1 extra pixel, and some are not.

Comment: @delinear but most likely in the same situation (i.e. viewport width)  this would produce different margins: 1 px for the first one and 2px for the second one...

Comment: @Johannes Oh for sure it doesn't fix the issue of the margins not being calculated equally, but in fairness the question as originally asked was about the margins disappearing completely, my suggestion was only a response to that, this new requirement that they must always be equal is a different question.

Comment: @delinear well, I was just referring to the problem as shown in the image the OP posted, where there is *no* margin between element 1 and 2, but there *is* a margin between 2 and 3... (and 1px vs. 2 px would be a clearly visible difference)